# Partition of graph without cycles

Tags: graph-theory

Let $D$ be the maximum degree of $G=(V,E)$, and $k=\lfloor {D \over 2}\rfloor +1$, prove that there exists a partition of $V=V_1 \cup V_2 \cup...\cup V_k$ such that each $V_i$ spans a subgraph without cycles.

I'm not sure how to approach the problem. It seems like induction would be the way to go, but with induction on $D$ it's not clear how to get to a graph with max degree less than $D$, and with induction on the number of vertices I get stuck too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that such a partition does not exist. In other words, for any partition $V = V_1 \uplus V_2 \uplus \ldots \uplus V_k$ there is an $i$ such that $G[V_i]$ contains a cycle.

For a moment, suppose that there is only one such $V_i$ and let $v \in V_i$ be any vertex that belongs to a cycle. Then $\deg_{V_i}(v) \geq 2$, however, moving that vertex into any other $V_j$ would also create a cycle, so $\deg_{V_j}(v) \geq 2$ as well. Summing that up we get $\deg_G(v) = \sum_{j=1}^{k}\deg_{V_j}(v) \geq 2k$. However, $k = \lfloor D/2 \rfloor + 1$, that is $\deg_G(v) \geq D+1$, a contradiction.

For a general case there can be multiple $V_i$ that contain cycles. However,

- either there is a vertex $v \in V_i$ that creates a cycle with each of the $V_j$ for $j = 1,\ldots,k$, but then the above reasoning applies;
- you can move a vertex $v \in V_i$ into some other $V_j$ decreasing the number of vertices that belong to cycles and this process cannot go on forever (the number of vertices on cycles is bounded by $n$).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

induction can be applied:
for n=3 It's obvious we have three vertice $ v_1 , v_2, v_3 $
Highest possible degree here could be 2 so:
$ V_1=v_1 $ $V_2$={$v_2, v_3$}

Suppose that the claim is true for all m where m < n:
Let'a look at our G=(V,E) where |V|=n.
Take a vertex $ v\in V $ such v has the minimal degree so we know that d(v)<=d.
If we now look at V-{v} this graph has m=n-1 vertices and still has maximal degree of d (we didn't delete the vertex with the maximal degree) therefore by induction where's a decomposition into k=d/2+1 disjoint vertice group. Now if the v we removed closes a cycle in each of $ V_1, V_2,..., V_k $ it must be that it has at least 2 edges going into each component whereby it has to have at least 2k edges meaning d(v)>2k-1=d+1 but we don't have that many edges (bouded by d edges max degree) so where exists a component $V_j$ such that v joined with it doesn't close a cycle, so none of the groups have a cycle and where is exactly k disjoint vertice groups as such.
[image]